# Create Trigger Mysql

Tags: mysql

After insert in the table Aluguel update field Status to busy.

Not work.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_Status_Update AFTER INSERT 
ON aluguel 
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE apartamento SET status_apart = busy
        WHERE id_apart = apartamento_id_apart; 
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `WHERE id_apart = NEW.apartamento_id_apart`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use new key word

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_Status_Update AFTER UPDATE

ON aluguel  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN UPDATE apartamento SET status_apart = new.busy

WHERE id_apart = new.apartamento_id_apart;

END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

---------------------------------------insert trigger -----------------

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_Status_Insert AFTER INSERT

ON aluguel  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN UPDATE apartamento SET status_apart = new.busy

WHERE id_apart = new.apartamento_id_apart;

END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: The question says that he wants it to be done after insert.

Comment: @RamonChaves try my answer instead of your one  you have typo in your sql

Comment: Busy is not a field. Is a value

Comment: in that case just remove that new key word

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a column from the table you're inserting into, you need to use `NEW.column_name`.

And if `busy` is a string, you need to put it in quotes.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_Status_Update AFTER INSERT 
ON aluguel 
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE apartamento SET status_apart = 'busy'
        WHERE id_apart = NEW.apartamento_id_apart; 
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c32a3/1)

Comment: It needs to be in quotes.

Comment: After making the insert . He compares the apartamento_id_apart the Aluguel table with id_part of Apartamento table. Just do not be working.